# Kubernetes error: Cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch", I am using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy a job that downloads a file to a PVC that I have successfully created. The method of deploying the job is by applying a yaml with the kubectl at command line (on windows).

```
kubectl apply -f file-download.yaml
```

I get this error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "file-download.yaml": jobs.batch is forbidden: User "token-{my user token}" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "{my context}"
```

I read that I must create a role and then bind that role to either the user or the job. So I did:

**role.yaml**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: mycontext
  name: example-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

**binding.yaml**

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-rolebinding
  namespace: mycontext
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: token-mytoken
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: example-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

What I am looking to find out if I have done this correctly, and also how do you 'invoke' these files such that the new rules apply to what I am trying to do? Is it sufficient to leave these two files in the working directory, of is there a kubectl command to apply them, for example (Or maybe a spot in the file-download.yaml that I have to reference these files?

Comment: *and also how do you 'invoke' these files such that the new rules **apply** to what I am trying to do?* heh, the answer is `for i in role.yaml binding.yaml; do kubectl apply -f $i; done` which will obviously need to be done by someone with the rights to create those objects themselves

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Try this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72087097/kubectl-get-secrets-error-from-server-forbidden) may help to resolve your issue.